# How can I implement JQuery promise and .map()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, web

I have an array. Usually the array has around 5 objects. And I hope the system will loop the array, each object in the array will generate a window(I use kendo window). And users will do some manipulations in the prompted window, after the ajax send the value and successfully returned the value. The window will be closed, and then prompt up the next window based on the object in the array. So how can I make .each() wait until the window closed then open another window?

I know JQuery promise, and .map(), but I don't know how to implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at below code snippet. I have simulated async behavior(window sequences) with `setTimeout`. Creating kendoUI window code goes where I have used `setTimeout`

No jQuery promise is being used. All are plain javascript.

```js
var array = [3, 6, 2, 5, 10],
    iTaskCounter = -1;

function doSomething(item, fnNextJob) {
  // Showing dialog and doing something
  // Now mocked with setTimeout
  console.log("Task: ", item);
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Calling next task");
    fnNextJob();
  }, item * 1000);
}

function executeTask() {
    iTaskCounter++;
    if(iTaskCounter < array.length) {
      doSomething(array[iTaskCounter], executeTask);
    } else {
      console.log("Task completed");
    }
}
console.log("Start task");
executeTask();
```

Comment: Very interesting point. Actually, you give excellent method names. DoSomeThing then call ExcuteTask. ExcuteTask will read data from the array, then determine what will do next. Like, two methods keep calling each other.  One does judge, another one does something.

Comment: Thanks so much. This is more clear than using JQuery Promise

Comment: Glad you like that solution :)